# Springboot mongoDb atlas search with Pattern in all feilds

Tags: mongodb, search, spring-data-jpa

i have a projet in springboot with database mongodb with pagenation , i have to make search with pattern in all fields of my structure
i tried search in mongo by creating index in all the collection , and field by field but in the both cases the search dont work correctly and must precise the field name when i use aggregation function $Search like this :

```
    index: 'default',
compound: {
        should: [
            {
                autocomplete: {
                    query:'pattern',
                    path: 'title',
                },
            },
            {
                autocomplete: {
                    query:'pattern',
                    path: 'name',
                },
            },
        ],
    },
```

i would know if there is any better solution (name of function or technic) with mongodb or using filters in springboot over data returned in all fields
thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest the idea i found maybe it will help someone someday , the idea is :
with using the java reflection we parse our class and get all fields and stock the in an array then we make aggregation "$regex" in all fields this approch maybe not the best solution but it helps cause we can also convert the numbers , timestamp to date to make a global research on all fields
enjoy coding :)